# Can I output only a css file using an entry point?

Tags: webpack-2, extract-text-plugin

I'm trying to find a way to only output a `.css` file and not a `.js` file with it. I cannot seem to find an automated way to handle this.

**Example (simplified)**

```
entry: {
    polyfill: [
        'babel-polyfill',
        'react-fastclick'
    ],

    app: [
        './js/index.js',
    ],

    styles: [
        './styles/global.scss'
    ]
}
```

Because I want to use `[chunkname]` for caching purposes, I cannot append the `global.scss` to the `app` entry.

Any ideas on how to not output a `.js` file for the `styles` entry?